# Can we add html 5 tags to sharepoint hosted app

Tags: 2013

From a SharePoint hosted app, I want to add some html 5 tags in my SharePoint hosted app which will be deployed to office 365 tenants.

Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do so. The compatibility of what you can use depend on the type of browser you're using to use your App, not SharePoint itself. To have a guidance of what you can do, use this site: http://caniuse.com . It will help you determine which browsers will suport your HTML5 tags.